# How to add an Id for material ui Raised Button component?

Tags: material-ui

I want to set a hidden property for the sign in button,

```
 <RaisedButton id='signInButton' label="Sign in" />
```

but doesnt seem to work.
any suggestions?

Comment: apparently there is no documented way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This works for me

The expected behaviour for your snippet above:

`<RaisedButton id='signInButton' label="Sign in" />`

should place an `id` attribute onto the `button` element created by `RaisedButton`.

I haven't tried this in other versions but in MUI 0.17.4. this works as expected.

**Note: it is the `button` element that the `id` attribute is applied to not the root `div` element.**

Also, `id` is one of the props specifically looked for and applied to the `button` so `Id` or `ID` would be ignored. I couldn't find in the source where this happens but I did test.

If that isn't helpful then let us know the MUI version, and the specific steps we can take to reproduce.